# Force Blender to Select rig instead of geometry

Tags: objects, 3d-view, selection-tools

I made a very simple ball rig in Blender. Nothing special. I have noticed, however, that it is difficult to select the rig without zooming in, and selecting and moving the geometry can cause issues. Is there a way to make blender detect when I try to select the geometry, and then redirect it to select the rig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For cases like this, I just switch to wireframe shading with <kbd>Z</kbd>, select the armature (which is now visable) then switch back to solid shading, again with <kbd>Z</kbd>.

---

Or you can turn off viewport selection, then you will not be able to select the mesh in the 3D view (you can still select it from the outliner).
[image: viewport selection button]

---

Another option is to select the armature differently. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> on your armature, that will bring up a list of objects that is below the mouse. You can pick your armature from that list.
[image: object selection list]

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll just switch into wire frame mode when I need to select it.